# Android Offline Highscore security/anticheat

Tags: android, security, offline

I'm creating an android game. I would like to know how can i register the highscore of the player offline. I can use SharedPreferences but rooted users would not be able to modify it. I have already created an anti-cheat system, so that apps like GameCIH, GameKiller... could not modify current game score.
Hope you will help me ! I'm french sorry for my pour english

Comment: Cryptography to the rescue. Or maybe there's some idiomatic way of doing this in android. If not, look into digital signatures and/or encryption. Signatures can ensure integrity, that something hasn't been altered. I'm guessing reading rights isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

You can simply use Leaderboards option on Google Play Game Services. It's easy to integrate if you follow their documents.